# Fourier-Mukai functors and autoequivalence groups of $G$-equivariant derived categories

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, derived-categories, fano-varieties

I have a few questions about $G$-equivariant derived categories. For my question, I'm assuming $G$ is cyclic. Also, in my case $G$ does not act on $X$, only on $D^b(X)$.

**Q1:** Orlov's Representability Theorem states that any fully faithful functor between derived categories of smooth projective varieties is Fourier-Mukai. Is there a version of this theorem for $G$-equivariant derived categories? In other words, if $X$ and $X'$ are smooth projective varieties and $\Phi^G : D^b(X)^G \simeq D^b(X')^G$ is fully faithful (actually, for my purposes $\Phi^G$ can be an equivalence), is it true that $\Phi^G$ is Fourier-Mukai? If the notion of a Fourier-Mukai functor even makes sense for $G$-equivariant derived categories... By David Ploog's paper *Equivariant autoequivalences for finite group actions* the concept does seem to extend.

**Q2:** If $X$ is Fano or general type, we know by Bondal-Orlov that $\mathrm{Aut}(D^b(X)) = \mathrm{Aut}(X) \ltimes (\mathrm{Pic}(X) \oplus \mathbb{Z})$. Can we conclude anything about $\mathrm{Aut}(D^b(X)^G)$ (of course if $G$ acts appropriately on $D^b(X)$)? Again, David Ploog's paper seems useful for this since he compares $\mathrm{Aut}(D^b(X)^G)$ with $\mathrm{Aut}(D^b(X))^G$.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has yet chimed in, I'll try to at least partially address your questions.

1. The notion of a Fourier-Mukai functor does extend. If you have a $G$-variety $X$ and a $H$-variety $Y$, then the pullback functor $\pi^*:D^b_G(X) \to D^b_{G \times H}(X \times Y)$ exists and is in fact essentially just the normal pullback. Similarly, the pushforward functor exists (with one minor modification, you need to take $G$-invariants). More details about this can be found in  [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9908027). Now whether or not every fully faithful functor with an adjoint is such a functor, it seems the answer is not completely clear. Kawamata has a paper [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40067887?seq=5#metadata_info_tab_contents) which addresses the question in a particular case, but its not clear that its been done in full generality. However it could turn out to be easy, and so no one has really written it down.
2. It will very much depend on the group action in question. For example in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.05405) that authors give a handful of examples of an abelian surface with group action such that the quotient is $\mathbb{P}^2$. Thus it would follow that the automorphism group of $D^b(A)$ is not really so related to the automorphism group of $D^b_G(A) \cong D^b(\mathbb{P}^2)$.

Hope this helps.